# ETL tool or ad-hoc solutions?

Tags: postgresql, etl, data-warehouse, data-cleaning

I'm designing a data warehouse system, the origin data sources are two: files (hexadecimal format, record structure known) and PostgreSQL database.
The ETL phase has to read the content of the two sources (files and DB) and combining/integrating/cleaning them. After this, loading data into the DW.

For this purpose, is better a tool (for example Talend) or ad-hoc solution (writing ad-hoc routines by using a programming language)?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the [Bulk Loader](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/PostgreSQL+Bulk+Loader) to get your flat file into DB. This allows you to customize the loading rules and then process/cleanse the resulting data set using regular SQL (no other custom code to write)

Comment: Maybe a good idea but I need to read deeply the content of the hexadecimal files.
I mean, read first two bytes and get the ID of my object, then read next n bytes and get the timestamp of my object and so on... Once collected information extracted from the files, cleaning them, integrated them with some data in the database and than loading into the data mart.